# Reference needed for surjectivity of reduction on prime residue class group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, ring-theory

If $n,m$ are positive integers such that $m \mid n$, then the natural map $$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \to (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{\times},~ [z] \mapsto [z]$$
is surjective. This has appeared a number of times on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32875) and [math.stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487011)[exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70717). See also [MO/31495](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31495) for more general observations.

But I am not asking for a proof. I wonder if someone knows a **reference** in the literature for this fact. I would like to cite it. So a blog post or lecture notes unfortunately are not good enough. Ideally it should be a textbook, ideally written in english.

An equivalent statement is the following (and actually this formulation is what I need): The automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ acts transitively on the subset of elements of order $m$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Thank you. Do you mean "A classical introduction to number theory" by Ireland + Rosen? I have skimmed through the first chapters but couldn't find it so far. Anyway, you can make this an answer if it is there.

Comment: I have found it: Number 4 [here](http://www.math.kent.edu/~white/qual/list/ring.pdf). Its a typical exam question. This does not qualify as reference for you, I know, but I think it will be in many algebra books (at least under "exercises").

Comment: Well I couldn't find it so far in those algebra books where I looked.

Comment: [K. Meyberg](https://www.google.at/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Algebra:+Mit+287+%C3%9Cbungsaufgaben&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgecToyS3w8sc9YSmHSWtOXmO04uIKzsgvd80rySypFNLhYoOylLgEpHj00_UNDY0rs8uzC5M1GKT4uFBEeAC5MHg_TgAAAA), Section rings, Exercise $16$, page $28$ in the exercise book "Aufgaben und Lösungen zur Algebra", 1978.

Comment: You can cite Math Overflow too and it qualifies to be a reference , even though this fact does not deserve to be cited as it's a well known exercise but it depends on the target audiance . See http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/402/in-writing-a-research-paper-how-can-i-refer-to-peoples-answers-given-to-a-ques